# Core Data fetch not working on real device - Core Data Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

The app works as follows:
There is a built-in persistent store (3 files of course) in the bundle. When the app launches, it copies the store into the core data directory (for the first time only) and starts to fetch it.

1. Core data fetches work fine on simulator, but won't fetch anything on real devices plugged in the computer. Here is the code for AppDelegate, CoreDataStack, ViewController fetch and the function that copies the store to the app directory.
2. Also, I failed to use fetch distinct result, simply I couldn't put the distinct results into an array. Instead I use I very bad way that fetches all and put them into a set.

The first question is the one that needs immediate solution. Any advice and help is MUCH appreciated!

```
// application function of AppDelegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

_ = coreDataStack.mainContext

    guard let tabc = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
        fatalError("Tab bar controller mis-configured.")
    }

    // Set the status bar to white

    guard let navc1 = tabc.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
        let wordLibVC = navc1.topViewController as? WordLibraryViewController else {
            fatalError("Navigation controller[0] mis-configured.")
    }
    wordLibVC.coreDataStack = coreDataStack
    wordLibVC.levelDict = levelDict

    return true
}

// Core Data Stack Class
class CoreDataStack {

// MARK: - Properties
fileprivate let modelName: String

var storeDirectory: URL = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()

lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.container.viewContext
}()

lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)

    self.seedCoreDataContainerIfFirstLaunch()

    container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in

        if let error = error as? NSError {

            fatalError("Could not load persistent stores. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()

init(modelName: String) {
    self.modelName = modelName
}
}

// fetch function in ViewController
func executeRequest() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Word>(entityName: "Word")
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["level"]

    let levelSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "level", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [levelSort]

    do {
        // The following line returns an empty array
        let results = try coreDataStack.mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        // The above line returns an empty array
        var levels: [Int] = []
        for result in results {
            levels.append(Int(result.level))
        }
        let distinctLevels = Set(levels)
        let sortedLevels = Array(distinctLevels).sorted()
        print(sortedLevels)
        let stringLevels = sortedLevels.map{String($0)}
        dataSource.append(stringLevels)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

// This is the function that copies the store from the bundle to the directory
func seedCoreDataContainerIfFirstLaunch() {

    let previouslyLaunched = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "previouslyLaunched")
    if previouslyLaunched { return }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "previouslyLaunched")

    // 1. sqlite file
    let destSQLite = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("wordlib.sqlite")
    let sourceSQLite = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "wordlib", withExtension: "sqlite")!
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destSQLite)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceSQLite, to: destSQLite)
        print("wordlib.sqlite seeded.")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not copy sqlite file, \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // 2. sqlite-shm file
    let destSHM = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("wordlib.sqlite-shm")
    let sourceSHM = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "wordlib", withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destSHM)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceSHM, to: destSHM)
        print("wordlib.sqlite-shm seeded.")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not copy shm file. \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // 3. .sqlite-wal
    let destWAL = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("wordlib.sqlite-wal")
    let sourceWAL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "wordlib", withExtension: "sqlite-wal")!
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destWAL)
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceWAL, to: destWAL)
        print("wordlib.sqlite-wal seeded.")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription), Could not copy wal file.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Specifying `propertiesToFetch` is only useful if the result type is `NSDictionaryResultType`. And what is that Set-Array-sorting dance for? The fetch result is supposed to be sorted according to the sort descriptor.

Comment: @vadian, oh ok, I thought propertiesToFetch will be a bit of a performance enhancement. Actually the sortDescriptor doesn't even work here -- the results is not sorted without the sorted() method.

Comment: How does the data come into core data in the first place?

Comment: @shallowThought There is a built-in persistent store (3 files of course) in the bundle. When the app launches, it copies the store into the core data directory (for the first time only) and start to fetch it.

Comment: Can I please see the code that copies the sqlite databases into the documents directory?

Comment: @A.Jam Updated.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? If it is not 10K records, it is better to import it from a text file or similar upon first start.

Comment: @Mundi It is about 25K records.

Comment: Should be no problem importing in the background.

Comment: @Mundi Would you elaborate it a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

After days of struggling, this problem is solved.

The OS and iOS file systems have different requirements:

OS file names are not case sensitive, while iOS file names are case sensitive.

Also, when loading persistent store, core data is trying to find a store file with the exactly same name as your data model. So if you have same spelling but different case file names you will not be able to fetch anything on real device, while fine on simulator.

Therefore, it is always recommended to have the data model and store file exactly the same name, if you have only one store file.